# Dialog API's messageParent not working with OWA

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm using the Office Javascript API for my Outlook add-in. I am running outlook-web-16.01 (`https://outlook.live.com/owa/`).

I can get the dialog popup by calling [`UI.displayDialogAsync`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync). But calling [`UI.messageParent`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.messageparent) doesn't result in `DialogMessageReceived` getting triggered on the parent page. I am running both parent and dialog on the same domain.

Manually closing the dialog does however trigger `DialogEventReceived` on the parent and with a `12006`.

I also noticed that the dialog has this error on the JS console right after loading, but not sure if it is related:

> Failed to execute `'postMessage'` on `'DOMWindow'`: The target origin provided (`'https://outlook.live.com'`) does not match the recipient window's origin (`'MyOrigin'`).

I am using the [OfficeDev example from GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Dialog-API-Simple-Example/tree/master/SimpleDialogSampleWeb).

My code to launch the dialog on the parent page copied from [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Dialog-API-Simple-Example/blob/master/SimpleDialogSampleWeb/DialogHelper.js),

```js
function dialogCallback(asyncResult) {
  if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {

      // In addition to general system errors, there are 3 specific errors for 
      // displayDialogAsync that you can handle individually.
      switch (asyncResult.error.code) {
          case 12004:
              console.log("Domain is not trusted");
              break;
          case 12005:
              console.log("HTTPS is required");
              break;
          case 12007:
              console.log("A dialog is already opened.");
              break;
          default:
              console.log(asyncResult.error.message);
              break;
      }
  }
  else {
      dialog = asyncResult.value;
      /*Messages are sent by developers programatically from the dialog using office.context.ui.messageParent(...)*/
      dialog.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, messageHandler);

      /*Events are sent by the platform in response to user actions or errors. For example, the dialog is closed via the 'x' button*/
      dialog.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogEventReceived, eventHandler);

      console.log(`handler registered`);
  }
}

function messageHandler(arg) {
    console.log(`handler called`);
    dialog.close();
    console.log(arg.message);
}

function eventHandler(arg) {

    // In addition to general system errors, there are 2 specific errors 
    // and one event that you can handle individually.
    switch (arg.error) {
        case 12002:
            console.log("Cannot load URL, no such page or bad URL syntax.");
            break;
        case 12003:
            console.log("HTTPS is required.");
            break;
        case 12006:
            // The dialog was closed, typically because the user the pressed X button.
            console.log("Dialog closed by user");
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Undefined error in dialog window");
            break;
    }
}

  var dialogUrl = 'MyOrigin/outlook/function-file/dialog.html';
  Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(dialogUrl, { height: 50, width: 50 }, dialogCallback);
```

And for the dialog HTML, I am doing exactly the same of [this code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Dialog-API-Simple-Example/blob/master/SimpleDialogSampleWeb/Dialog.html).

Comment: Which browser are you using to reproduce this? Is office.initialize being called for dialog?

Comment: Is this resolved? My suggestion is to add all your domains in the allowed list in the manifest file.

Comment: @Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT : Can you please confirm on this. I am still facing this issue in Jan 2019.

Comment: @Curious Explorer: we have not been able to repro this. Could you provide more details on your repro: for example: whether urls are in allowed list in manifest, are using same urls in dialog and addin, the browser you are using, error you are seeing, code snippet to repro?

Comment: I am having a similar problem with my add-in dialog after changing the displayInIframe dialog setting to false. When displayInIframe is true, the call to messageParent is successful. Unfortunately, my app requires a non-iframe dialog.

Comment: @jmarq Same here I could also not use the iframe on due to live.com not allowing the login window in iframe.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Have put up a separate question as I am not sure if this question's exact problem is same as mine and if I can put up so much code in comments. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087582/officejs-outlook-addin-dialog-apis-messageparent-not-working-with-owa

Comment: @CodingFanSteve did you solve this issue? I am working on Addin and have the same problem as you. messageParent does not work, but closing the window triggeres "close event". Any way to solve it? I see "displayinIframe" can be set to true to fix it, but my auth app does not allow iFrames (Auth0)

Answer (score 1):

After debugging Microsoft Office library I found the issue. 
In order for messaging to work properly, your URL's in manifest files should be prefixed with the https://

As soon as I updated my Manifest, it all starts working.

Just make sure your URLs in AppDomains prefixed with https://

```
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://app.polarcrm.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:44321</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
```

This is the details of my implementation:
https://yaplex.com/blog/office-addin-messageparent-not-working

[image]